# Find the cell location of the maximum value of an array if the lookup column is uknown

Tags: excel, match, lookup

I am trying to obtain the location of the maximum value in an excel spreadsheet (see below).

```
Date    Tommy   Jamie   Clara
01/2013 1.51%   -6.96%  0.38%
02/2013 1.75%   -6.96%  -0.49%
03/2013 2.22%   -6.96%  0.59%
04/2013 1.90%   -5.48%  -1.16%
05/2013 2.03%   -5.48%  0.23%
06/2013 1.90%   -5.48%  -0.47%
07/2013 2.51%   -0.90%  -0.65%
08/2013 3.06%   -0.90%  1.54%
```

The problem in this case however is that both the row and column numbers are not known. So far I have tried the following:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($B$1:$D$9, MATCH(MAX($B$1:$D$9),$B$1:$D$9,0),3))
```

but realized that the MATCH function will only accept a single column, hence the second argument of the MATCH function herein produces an error. Likewise, the third argument of the INDEX function (written as "3") would be wrong as well - since I do not know what column the maximum value of the array would lie.

I tried various stuff but to no avail. Would be glad to get any assistance in this regard.

Comment: first why are you trying to return the address?  Are you going to use that in another formula?  What is the desired end result, not just this step but the end result.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner. I need the address to determine the Date and Name of the Sales agent that corresponds with the maximum value.

Comment: Then you are doing too many steps.  With the AGGREGATE approach below you can return the column and the row to and index that returns the values directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=CELL("address";INDEX($A$1:$D$9; AGGREGATE(14;6;(ROW($B$2:$D$9)/(MAX($B$2:$D$9)=$B$2:$D$9));1);AGGREGATE(14;6;(COLUMN($B$2:$D$9)/(MAX($B$2:$D$9)=$B$2:$D$9));1)))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

I assume that you are familiar with the CELL and INDEX functions, so I will only explain the `AGGREGATE` part.

```
AGGREGATE(14,6,(ROW($B$2:$D$9)/(MAX($B$2:$D$9)=$B$2:$D$9)),1)
```

The first argument `(14)` indicates that the `LARGE` subfunction will be used.

The second argument `(6)` indicates that errors will be ignored.

The third argument creates an array of row number values.

The fourth argument `(1)` states that the first largest value should be returned.

I will show you how an array of row numbers is created in steps:

1. `ROW(B2:D9)` returns an array with all row numbers in the range:

```
2,2,2;
3,3,3;
4,4,4;
...
9,9,9
```

2. `MAX($B$2:$D$9)=$B$2:$D$9` returns a bool array:

```
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE;
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE;
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE;
...
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
```

3. Dividing by each other, bool values ​​are converted to FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1, resulting in an array:

```
  #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!;
  #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!;
  #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!;
 ...
  9, #DIV/0!, #DIV/0!
```

4. Errors are ignored and as a result we get `9`

The column is calculated analogously.

If there are several identical MAX values ​​in the range, then this formula will not work - you can use the following array formula instead:

```
=ADDRESS(INT(MIN(IF($B$2:$D$9=MAX($B$2:$D$9),ROW($B$2:$D$9)*1000+COLUMN($B$2:$D$9)))/1000),MOD(MIN(IF($B$2:$D$9=MAX($B$2:$D$9),ROW($B$2:$D$9)*1000+COLUMN($B$2:$D$9))),1000),4)
```

It will return address of the first MAX value.

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Comment: Many thanks @basic: the code works. If you permit me, there are two things I'd like to ask. (1) could you please provide a bit of an explanation as to how the code works? (2) I just imagined what would happen if I apply this to hundreds to rows/cols -- and there are more than one cells with the same value as maximum. Are any adjustments necessary?

Comment: Many thanks @basic. I really do appreciate your help. Best regards.